# rosmsg show unable to load message [std_msgs/]

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I am a newbie to ROS and know absolutely nothing about it. I am following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/otGWUZqB9XE?si=4U5ESuUyJhqvQlSk&t=329) and at 5:33 he enters the following command `rosmsg show std_msgs/` and when I do the same in the terminal i get the following error, and I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried looking for an answer in other places but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error:

```
Unable to load msg [std_msgs/]: Cannot locate message [] in package [std_msgs] with paths [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/std_msgs/msg']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user in the video is pressing the `tab` key to get a list of possible completions of `rosmsg show std_msgs/`, you are pressing 'enter' and tring to execute that command, but it's invalid, it wants a specific message to show.  (It'd be helpful if the video creator was using a program to show which keys they were pressing on screen)

```
rosmsg show std_msgs/
```

don't press enter, press tab, then get this output:

```
std_msgs/Bool                 std_msgs/Empty                std_msgs/Int16                std_msgs/Int8                 std_msgs/UInt16               std_msgs/UInt8
std_msgs/Byte                 std_msgs/Float32              std_msgs/Int16MultiArray      std_msgs/Int8MultiArray       std_msgs/UInt16MultiArray     std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray
std_msgs/ByteMultiArray       std_msgs/Float32MultiArray    std_msgs/Int32                std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension  std_msgs/UInt32               
std_msgs/Char                 std_msgs/Float64              std_msgs/Int32MultiArray      std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout     std_msgs/UInt32MultiArray     
std_msgs/ColorRGBA            std_msgs/Float64MultiArray    std_msgs/Int64                std_msgs/String               std_msgs/UInt64               
std_msgs/Duration             std_msgs/Header               std_msgs/Int64MultiArray      std_msgs/Time                 std_msgs/UInt64MultiArray
```

I usually do this to get a list of possible messages without using the tab completion:

```
rosmsg list | grep std_msgs
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I was going crazy haha.